# Getting a Java error message saying java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, loops, nosuchelementexception

I'm working on a Bank assignment that is supposed to output a menu and allow user input to select what they want to do. The program is to loop and receive user input until the user enters "Q" for quit. After I loop once, there is an error message popping up saying java.util.NoSuchElementException.

Here is my code:

**Bank.java**

```
import java.util.*;


public class Bank
{
    static BankAccount[] accounts;
    static int noOfAccs;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        noOfAccs = 0;
        accounts = new BankAccount[noOfAccs + 1];
        bankMenu();
    }
    
    // run menu
    static void bankMenu()
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int currentIndex = -1;
        String choice;

        do
        {
            printMenu(currentIndex);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter command: ");
            choice = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            // uppercase the input
            choice = choice.toUpperCase();
            
            switch(choice)
            {
                case "O":
                    openAcc(currentIndex);

                    // if there is no room, resize
                    if (accounts.length == noOfAccs)
                    {
                        accounts = resize();
                    }

                    break;
                
                case "D":
                    if (currentIndex != -1)
                    {
                        double amount;
                        System.out.print("Enter amount of deposit: ");
                        amount = scnr.nextDouble();
                        accounts[currentIndex].deposit(amount);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please select an account");
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                    break;

                case "S":
                    try
                    {  
                        selectAcc(currentIndex);
                        currentIndex = selectAcc(currentIndex);
                        int index = currentIndex;
                    }
                    
                    catch(NoSuchElementException index)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Account number was not found");
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                    break;

                case "C":
                    if (currentIndex != -1)
                    {
                        closeAcc(currentIndex);
                        currentIndex = -1;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please select an account");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    break;

                // FIXME: "account cannot be resolved to a variable"
                
                case "W":
                    double amount;
                    if (currentIndex != -1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw: ");
                        amount = scnr.nextDouble();
                        accounts[currentIndex].withdraw(amount);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please select an account");
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                    break;

                case "L":
                    listAccounts();
                    break;

                case "Q":
                    break;
            }
            
        } while(!choice.equals("Q"));

        scnr.close();
    }

    // print menu
    // double check this
    static void printMenu(int currentIndex)
    {
        System.out.println("O: Open account");
        System.out.println("D: Deposit");
        System.out.println("S: Select account");
        System.out.println("C: Close account");
        System.out.println("W: Withdraw");
        System.out.println("L: List all accounts");
        System.out.println("Q: Quit");
        System.out.println();

        // if no account is selected
        if (currentIndex == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("current account selected: NONE");
        }

        // FIXME: might be wrong
        else
        {
            System.out.println("current account selected: " + accounts[currentIndex].getAcc()
                                + "\tBalance: $" + accounts[currentIndex].getBalance());
        }
    }

    // open bank acc
    static BankAccount openAcc(int currentIndex)
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int acc;
        double bal;
        boolean accExists = false;

        System.out.print("Enter NEW account number: ");
        acc = scnr.nextInt();

        // step through list
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfAccs; ++i)
        {
            // check if account exists
            if (accounts[currentIndex].getAcc() == acc)
            {
                accExists = true;
            }
        }

        if (accExists)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Account already exists.");
        }

        // continue, get balance
        else
        {
            // increment number of accounts
            ++noOfAccs;
            ++currentIndex;

            System.out.print("Enter initial balance: ");
            bal = scnr.nextDouble();
            System.out.println();

            // store new account in arrayList
            BankAccount newAcc = new BankAccount(acc, bal);
            accounts[currentIndex] = newAcc;
        }

        scnr.close();
        return accounts[currentIndex];
    }

    // resize array (double the size)
    // FIXME: is probably wrong
    static BankAccount[] resize()
    {
        BankAccount[] resized = new BankAccount[noOfAccs * 2];
        
        // copy elements to temp
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfAccs; ++i)
        {
            resized[i] = accounts[i];
        }

        accounts = resized;
        return accounts;
    }

    // diplay accounts
    static void listAccounts()
    {
        if (noOfAccs == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: No accounts.");
            System.out.println();
        }

        else
        {
            double totalAssets = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < noOfAccs; ++i)
            {
                System.out.print( (i + 1) + ") Acct #: " + accounts[i].getAcc());
                System.out.print("\t\tBal: $" + accounts[i].getBalance());
                System.out.println();
                totalAssets += accounts[i].getBalance();
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Total Bank assets: $" + totalAssets);
        }
    }

    // get account number
    static int selectAcc(int currentIndex)
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean found = false;
        int chosenAcc;

        // get chosenAcc
        System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
        chosenAcc = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        // search for chosenAcc
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfAccs; ++i)
        {
            if (accounts[i].getAcc() == chosenAcc)
            {
                found = true;
                currentIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if (found == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Account number was not found.");
            System.out.println();
        }

        scnr.close();
        return currentIndex;
    }

    // close account
    // move the last account in list to index of delted account
    static void closeAcc(int currentIndex)
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean accExists = false;
        int accToDelete;

        System.out.println("Please select an account");
        System.out.println();
        accToDelete = scnr.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfAccs; ++i)
        {
            if (accToDelete == accounts[i])
            {
                accExists = true;
                currentIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if (accExists == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Please select an account");
            System.out.println();
        }

        // move last account to deleted account's index
        else
        {
            accounts[currentIndex] = accounts[noOfAccs - 1];
            accounts[noOfAccs - 1] = null;
            --noOfAccs;
        }
    }
}


class BankAccount
{
    private int accNbr;
    private double balance;

    // constructor
    public BankAccount(int accNbr, double balance)
    {
        this.accNbr = accNbr;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    // retrieve acc number
    int getAcc()
    {
        return this.accNbr;
    }

    // retrieve acc balance
    double getBalance()
    {
        return this.balance;
    }

    // deposit
    void deposit(double amount)
    {
        this.balance += amount;
    }

    
    void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        // if less than $1
        if (this.balance < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Account balance insufficient for withdrawal");
            System.out.println();
        }

        // withdraw
        else
        {
            this.balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output with the error message. The input is given where it's asking the user to enter their choices. The input is "O", 123456, 100. Then from there, it outputs the menu again but doesn't let me input anything.

```
O: Open account
D: Deposit
S: Select account
C: Close account
W: Withdraw
L: List all accounts
Q: Quit

current account selected: NONE

Enter command: O

Enter NEW account number: 123456
Enter initial balance: 100

O: Open account
D: Deposit
S: Select account
C: Close account
W: Withdraw
L: List all accounts
Q: Quit

current account selected: NONE

Enter command: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
        at Bank.bankMenu(Bank.java:28)
        at Bank.main(Bank.java:13)
```

Comment: `scnr.close();` Don't close a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in` Remove that line of code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've provided over 350 lines of code - please try to reduce this to a *minimal* example demonstrating the problem. In doing that, you may well find the problem yourself.

Comment: @Abra it worked. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah you're right haha clearly I am new. Thanks for the advice I'll make sure to do that instead of having huge lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you close the scanner in the **openAcc** method. You should close only at the quitting from the program.